# Spatially joining only features by largest overlap with sjoin in GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, spatial-join, area, overlapping-features

I am using GeoPandas to join two GeoDataFrames with the parameter `how="inner", op="intersects"`.

Due to nature of the files a larger percentage of the files are duplicates (in regard of the geometry). Therefore I want to ask how to filter out and restrict to a single area, like selecting only output file entries with the highest Intersection over Union, DICE coefficient, Overlap coefficient or similar of the overlapping geometries.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code based on BERA`s answer worked for me:

```
df3 = gpd.overlay(df1, df2, how='intersection')
df3['area'] = df3.geometry.area
df3.sort_values(by='area', inplace=True)
df3.drop_duplicates(subset='ogc_fid', keep='last', inplace=True)
df3.drop(columns=['area'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: This one is definitely faster than my method. I just want to hint at the subset... And I personally would off the method to use the original left geometry

Answer (score 4):

Intersect, sort by area and drop duplicates:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import psycopg2

con = psycopg2.connect(database="lmv", user="postgres", password="dsfdas",
    host="localhost")

df1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis("select geom, lan_kod from ok_an_riks", con, geom_col='geom' )
df2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis("select geom, ogc_fid from ok_nd_riks", con, geom_col='geom' )

df3 = gpd.overlay(df1, df2, how='intersection')

#Sort by area so largest area is last
df3.sort_values(by=df3.geometry.area, inplace=True)

#Drop duplicates, keep last/largest
df3.drop_duplicates(subset='ogc_fid', keep='last', inplace=True)
```

Example:

```
print(df3.loc[df3['ogc_fid']==105][['lan_kod','ogc_fid']])
   lan_kod  ogc_fid
42      04      105
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks with your answer, but the it has two floors at least for me: 1.) ```df3.sort_values(by=df3.geometry.area, inplace=True)``` had to be rewritten to: ```df3.sort_values(by='geometry', inplace=True, key =lambda col: np.array([x.area for x in col]))```. 2.) Overlay seems to kit the left polygon, which I wanted to keep intact!

Comment: Than I have to reate a index for f1 as column, use it for filtering and than using the index to retrieve the original geometry? Before finally dropping i again? :(

Comment: Or dont you have some unique ID which you can use for the merge? For example I have the `ogc_fid` column

Comment: But it leaves the general question how to copy over the original geometries, without mixing it with the wrong attributes of the dataframe. I tried it with sorting with resport to the index and than simply copiing over the geometries, but that mixed up every thing badly!

Comment: Dont use the geometry column of the intersected dataframe, just join back the attributes to your original dataframe

Comment: Somehow I get `KeyError` exception at the sorting phase of this solution. Similar to this one, in @Night bird's answer, the error does not show up.

Answer (score 2):

When reading the answer by @BERA I came up the the following solution:

```py
current= gpd.tools.sjoin(left_gdf, right_gdf, how="inner", op="intersects")
current['intersection'] = [a.intersection(right_gdf[right_gdf.index == b].geometry.values[0]).area for a, b in zip(left_gdf.geometry.values, left_gdf.index_right)]
current= current.sort_values(by='geometry')
current= current.drop_duplicates(subset='intersection', keep='last')  # keep larger intersection
current= current.drop(columns=['index_right', 'intersection'])
```