# Spatial join of two polygons using GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, spatial-join, overlapping-features

I am trying to preform a spatial join between two vector files where i have one polygon-grid and a classified vector-file, as shown below:

[image: The two vector files used. Grid and classified data]

I would like to be able to classify my grid according to the majority class in each cell, so if it is mostly red etc. Similar to zonal statistics or rasterstats but for vectordata.

I tried using GeoPandas's `sjoin`

```
gpd.sjoin(grid, classified_vector)
```

but the result is clearly not based on majority of each class. I have tried using different switches in `sjoin` but without any luck.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My answer is a slight extension to [Spatially joining only features by largest overlap with sjoin in GeoPandas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389675/spatially-joining-only-features-by-largest-overlap-with-sjoin-in-geopandas)

Let's assume there are two polygon layers *'grid'* and *'layer'*, see the image below.

[image: input]

Using the following code:

```py
import geopandas as gpd

_layer = "C:/Downloads/geopandas/layer.shp"
_grid = "C:/Downloads/geopandas/grid.shp"

layer = gpd.read_file(_layer)
grid = gpd.read_file(_grid)

_overlay = gpd.overlay(grid, layer, how='intersection')

_overlay['area'] = _overlay['geometry'].area/10**6
_overlay.sort_values(by=['area'], inplace=True)
_overlay.drop_duplicates(subset='id', keep='last', inplace=True)

_overlay.drop(['fid', 'area', 'geometry'], inplace=True, axis=1)

grid_join = grid.join(_overlay.set_index('id'), on='id')

grid_join.to_file("grid_join.shp")
```

it is possible to achieve the desired output:

[image: result]

or a bit more clearer

[image: result_clear]

---

**References:**

- [GeoPandas Docs | Spatial Joins](https://geopandas.org/gallery/spatial_joins.html)
- [Pandas Docs | Join](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)
- [Spatially joining only features by largest overlap with sjoin in GeoPandas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389675/geopandas-sjoin-largest-filter-by-overlap)
- [Get a list from Pandas DataFrame column headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482970/get-a-list-from-pandas-dataframe-column-headers)
- [Delete a column from a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-a-column-from-a-pandas-dataframe)
- [JOIN two dataframes on common column in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41463119/join-two-dataframes-on-common-column-in-python)

Comment: Thanks! worked perfect!